# How to change a think cell object's name through VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am putting together a VBA module that calculates some data in Excel and pastes it in a powerpoint presentation. 
In this powerpoint presentation, I have some think cell charts, that I know I can update with the help of the tcaddin (see code below). What I didn't find though, is how I can identify a think cell chart on a given slide, or change the name of this object. The reason I need to do that is that I want to copy a chart and update it with another set of data than the one already used, but if I do that with the updatechart method, it will update both the original chart and the new one. I don't know before hands how many charts I will have total, so I can't produce them and name them in advance.

I've tried to use "ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Name" to identify the name of my think cell object, but this doesn't work (Error '-21447188160 (8048240) : selection (unknown member) : invalid request. Nothing appropriate is currently selected)
I've searched for similar questions, but the ones I found kinda matching my problem were not answered. Think Cell's help on the subject is not so deep (https://www.think-cell.com/en/support/manual/exceldataautomation.shtml) and I couldn't find any solutions in there.

```vb
Dim tcaddin As Object

    pptFileName = WSExec.Range("B18").Value

' Get the think-cell add-in object
Set tcaddin = Application.COMAddIns("thinkcell.addin").Object

'Get powerpoint object:
 On Error Resume Next
 Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
 On Error GoTo 0

'Get the presentation :
 If ppApp Is Nothing Then
     Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
     Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open( _
      Filename:=pptFileName, _
       Untitled:=msoFalse, _
       WithWindow:=msoTrue) 
 Else
     Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Item(1)
 End If

Call tcaddin.UpdateChart(ppPres, "ChartTrafficXEvol", WSExecSum.Range("J33:N52"), False)
```

I have no output to provide, but what I would like is some property on the tcaddin object, that would allow me to change the name of a chart or create a new one (and setting its name).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter in UpdateChart() can either be an entire presentation or a slide range. This means that you can create one template slide with a manually named think-cell chart and then copy the entire slide via VBA. The think-cell chart on the newly copied slide will have the same name as the original. You can then run UpdateChart() specifying only the new slide as the first parameter to update its data.

Comment: Is support for VBA ever going to be added?

Comment: This is not on our current roadmap. think-cell has a lot of automation built in, such as for placing labels and annotations when users interactively create charts, and we are always open to improve automated chart updating based on this, but a generic API is currently not expected.

As for the OOXML, think-cell creates all content with PP objects for compatibility. You can edit the OOXML freely, but charts may have to be reimported when later editing with think-cell again. Pls contact us via our website for more detail, I have a char limit here.

Regards, your think-cell support team.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will also write to you at the support center. What I would like to achieve is to resize multiple charts in different slides (each of them with multiple charts). I am considering XSLT to achieve this, however with VBA would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is useable only on native shapes, not Think-Cell shapes. Here is Think-Cell's statement on the subject: [Can I use my VBA macros with think-cell elements?](https://www.think-cell.com/en/support/kb/0032.shtml)

Comment: would it be possible to find/edit ThinkCell charts with OOXML, instead?

Comment: I have just checked and ThinkCell contents is visible from the XML, (`p:oleObj name="think-cell Slide ..."`), so the above (and many other ideas I've had so far) could be done with OOXML. Here is something I will try to do with your book I have recently bought :)